# High power PCB to PCB connector names?

Tags: power, pcb, connector

Trying something new out, I'd like to make an 'attachment' PCB that will slot into my mother-PCB, and all the questions here have said to use a kind of edge-to-edge connector or a ribbon connector.

My question is what exactly do I use for high power? Something like 2-3A rectified mains 170VDC.

Basically I know the 'mother' board works, but I don't know if the child board works, so I'd like to 'modularize' it.

Perhaps these things;

[image]

Would work? I just have no clue what they are called.

EDIT: Uhp, they're called banana connectors. Still don't know if they're good for high power PCB-PCB connection.

EDIT2: The boards will be side-by-side, edges touching.

EDIT3: *pic*

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if this is adequate? http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/J100-KIT/J100-KIT-ND/5878 a "banana" and a jack.

Comment: Banana connectors aren't usually used for board to board connectors. 2-3 amps @ 170 V isn't a ton of juice, there should be plenty of options of digikey or similar for board-to-board connectors.

Comment: Watts isn't what you need to consider in connectors and wiring... it's just amperage. Voltage matters, but only from an insulation breakdown point of view. One wire carrying 1V 1A will heat up exactly as much as a wire carrying 1000V 1A.

Comment: @darron Ohh, that makes a lot of sense actually. I completely blanked on that.

Comment: @darron: Not quite true. Since watts is what heats up the contacts and since \$ P = I^2 R \$, the higher the resistance of the contacts  or the higher the current through them, the more power they'll dissipate and the hotter they'll get

Comment: @EMFields Well, true of course... but not the wattage he was thinking about. When specifying a connector, you generally just need to consider amperage and maybe maximum voltage of the insulation.

Comment: Wait is there a different kind of wattage? I was under the impression that resistance was a kind of non-real value and in actuality the point-charge force and the associated friction (movement/time), i.e. voltage and current, were the determiners of resistance, not the other way around.

Comment: @EMFields is confusing you a bit. Wattage is wattage, but your 340-510W is not what he's talking about. He's talking about the watts lost in the connector or cable itself... which should be a fairly small number. 3A with say a 0.1 ohm resistance wire would be 0.9 W. If you notice on Digikey or whatever you tend to just see amperage ratings and maybe insulation breakdown voltages. The real resistance is likely to be way lower, anyway.

Comment: Oh so he's talking about the wattage lost during 'travel' (through a wire) as heat, and not the total effect of passing 500W through a conductor of X wattage rating into it's load?

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for GCT so express an interest.  We have some board to board connectors for co-planar PCB mating, these are aimed at LED lighting applications.  There are SMT and thru hole variations, they are available in 2-6 contacts and rated at 3A per contact.  I think you will find this an inexpensive solution for co-planar mating which is also available from stock in Newark/Farnell.

SMT = BG300 socket mating with BG301 Header

Thru Hole = BG302 socket mating with BG303 Header

Here is the GCT link for general information:
[GCT White Lite PCB Connectors](http://gct.co/pcb-board-to-board/whitelite.aspx?InsulatorColour=White&)

Link to Newark SMT headers [BG301](http://www.newark.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?st=bg301&catalogId=15003&categoryId=800000006604&langId=-1&storeId=10194)
Link to Newark SMT sockets [BG300](http://www.newark.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?st=bg300&catalogId=15003&categoryId=800000006604&langId=-1&storeId=10194)

Link to Farnell SMT headers [BG301](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&gs=true&st=bg301)  Link to Farnell SMT sockets [BG300](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?st=bg300&catalogId=15001&categoryId=700000005016&langId=44&storeId=10151)

Answer (score 3):

Use connectors **that are rated for the power you want**. They might be edge-to-edge or board-to-board, or wires. At some point they might have product names that are power-edge-to-edge or something similar at some arbitrary threshold, but they're all in the same category.

For instance:

[This connector](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/45719-0007/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtWxQ3D3EXBN1BtDMBGo%2FrGacTjYiqSti0%3D) is a standard card edge connector that is rated for 40A and 250V.

The main thing you need to figure out when choosing a different type of connector is how you want the boards to mate. Do you want a wire between two loose boards? Do you want them to slot in perpendicular? Do you want them to connect end-to-end? Etc.

Comment: Gotcha, guess I've got searching to do.

Comment: Not power, current. While @EMFields is correct in that it's ultimately power that heats the contacts and wires, it's not generally how you'd spec a contact. After all, you can't say that for instance 1000A at 5V is fine over that 40A 250V edge connector, since 5kW is way less than 10kW. It'd explode.

Comment: I agree with @darron here, EMFields is going on a tangent which while true is irrelevant. Current is the determining factor when searching for connectors, the contact resistance of the connector just helps determine the current rating! As well as possible high-speed signal degradation and voltage drop of course. But for DC power, go nuts as long as the isolation voltage is fine, and the current rating is correct for your application (x1.5 just to be safe lol)

Comment: The op specified a voltage and a current, that's power. No specification will specify a power rating, but looking at both factors is power.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/6643220-1/A101989-ND/2056032
and
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/6643274-1/A114321-ND/2305428

I think they are considered a "two piece power connectors" meant for hot-swap power electronics. I've seen them mostly on hot-swap power supplies.

Comment: It looks like the plug connects "up". These boards are gonna be side by side, you know? Like on the edge.

Comment: @ARMATAV: well, maybe if you'd put all your requirements in your question you'd get better answer. We can't read you mind.

Comment: First of all, I'm only learning what it's called right now, second; "I'd like to make an 'attachment' PCB that will slot into my mother-PCB, and all the questions here have said to use a kind of edge-to-edge connector".

Comment: @ARMATAV: I doubt "all" the questions have used card edge connectors. Using pin header connectors to stack boards would easily handle the voltage and current requirements and are cheap and easy to work with.

Comment: I'll go look for a side-by-side version of those then. I didn't think simple pin headers could handle that wattage. Thanks!

Comment: Explore Digikey, using that product as a start point. The catalog pages are full of these kinds of connectors...some even include extra pins for data and low current signals.

Comment: Could you include a quick drawing of your PCB configuration?

Comment: Just left home, will update for you when I'm back. If you need it immediately, imagine a U shaped PCB made so that a smaller one could slot into the middle of the U on the same plane. But to be honest, it's probably better if I draw it out. Will do when I'm back.

Comment: @hashbang Sorry dude, I'm back; is this what you meant by a quick configuration drawing? http://i.imgur.com/EWkxgqp.png

Comment: Yep, that helps a lot. I wasn't quite picturing that configuration. But it looks like someone else found a good connector for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try DIN41612 connectors - there are variants with special high-current pins.  Something like http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-41612-connectors/5424631/