# Soldering Alternatives for power cord to PCB

Tags: soldering

After [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81208/is-it-ok-to-solder-a-power-cord) and [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/81210/194044) I was wondering what are the soldering alternatives for low power applications, like supplied by 4 AA batteries.

I Found online that some use silicon glue and conductive glue as solder alternatives, but do not know if this is applicable on PCB's or not. Also [found this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159192/high-power-pcb-to-pcb-connector-names) but apparently it is for high power applications.

Comment: The answer you're referring to doesn't apply to low power, low voltage applications. In the worst case, say if your 4 AA batteries get shorted, will someone die? In any case, I'm pretty sure soldering is safer than whatever glue you planned to use.

Comment: You could use a connector, like the highly available JST connectors.

Comment: Solder a dc barrel jack onto the PCB and plug a wall wart into it. Or use a terminal block or barrier strip.